# Convert string to decimal within LINQ Average function while handling possible null values

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of exchange rates, stored in a DataTable, that I would like to group together while obtaining an average of the rates in a group. My problem has two parts.

1. The Rate is stored as a string and needs to be converted to a decimal before it van be averaged
2. The rate could be missing or null and if it is I don't want to include it in the average

So here is some sample data ...

```
+------------------+----------------+---------+
| OriginalCurrency | TargetCurrency |   Rate  |
+------------------+----------------+---------+
|        CAD       |       AUD      | 114.495 |
+------------------+----------------+---------+
|        GBP       |       EUR      | 116.111 |
+------------------+----------------+---------+
|        USD       |       GBP      |  77.993 |
+------------------+----------------+---------+
|        GBP       |       EUR      | 115.516 |
+------------------+----------------+---------+
|        USD       |       GBP      |  88.452 |
+------------------+----------------+---------+
|        CAD       |       AUD      | 112.774 |
+------------------+----------------+---------+
```

Here is the LINQ statement I have been working on ...

```
var groupedRates = exchangeRatesTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
.GroupBy(x => new
{
    OriginalCurrency = x.Field<string>("OriginalCurrency ").ToString(),
    TargetCurrency = x.Field<string>("TargetCurrency ").ToString(),
}).Select(y => new
{
    OriginalCurrency = y.Key.OriginalCurrency ,
    TargetCurrency = y.Key.TargetCurrency ,
    AverageRate = y.Average(r => r.Field<decimal>("Rate"))
});
```

I have the grouping working but the `Average` is not, because I cannot figure out how to convert the `string` representation of "Rate" into a `decimal`, within the `LINQ` statement. I am also not sure how to handle rows where the "Rate" is empty or missing.

Comment: ... thought about a little .Where(...) to filter out null or empty rates?

Comment: That is a good point. Didn't think about `Where()`. Thank you. Now just have to figure out the conversion within the LINQ statement.

Comment: Instead of `Rows.Cast<DataRow>()` use `.AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: Note that, if  ``y`` null or empty, ``Average`` throw an exception, i think the right way is:``y.Where(r => decimal.TryParse(r.Field<string>("Rate"), out _)).Select(r => decimal.Parse(r.Field<string>("Rate"))).DefaultIfEmpty().Average(x => x);``

Comment: You say that you need to handle the case where the rate field is a string that is (1) null, (2) empty, (3) a decimal, but you do not say whether you need to handle the case where the value is a non-empty, non-null string that is also not a legal decimal. Do you need to handle that case?

Comment: @EricLippert In the case where is is not a value that can be converted to a decimal, I would want to just toss the value and not include it in the average, essentially treating it the same as null or zero.

Comment: OK, then none of the answers proposed so far are correct.

Comment: @EricLippert Would the answer by @PabloCarballo be correct since it filters out null or empty with the `Where` clause first?

Comment: i think yes, but if the ``where``return empty list, ``average`` will throw an exception!?

Comment: @webworm: It does not filter out fields where Convert.ToDecimal fails because the string is not null, not empty, and not a legal decimal.

Comment: @Sajid: That's correct; that's a separate problem.

Comment: i think ``y.Where(r => decimal.TryParse(r.Field<string>("Rate"), out _)).Select(r => decimal.Parse(r.Field<string>("Rate"))).DefaultIfEmpty().Average(x => x);`` will work fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should filter out any row whose Rate is null or empty string since assuming that a null or empty string is equivalent to 0 may result in a wrong average calculation.
Then you can convert the property Rate to decimal:

```
var groupedRates = exchangeRatesTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
.Where(r => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Field<string>("Rate")))
.GroupBy(x => new
{
    OriginalCurrency = x.Field<string>("OriginalCurrency ").ToString(),
    TargetCurrency = x.Field<string>("TargetCurrency ").ToString(),
})
.Select(y => new
{
    OriginalCurrency = y.Key.OriginalCurrency ,
    TargetCurrency = y.Key.TargetCurrency ,
    AverageRate = y.Average(r => Convert.ToDecimal(r.Field<string>("Rate")))
});
```

Comment: Although the answer from @EricLippert was very detailed and explained things very well I felt this answer more directly answers the question for someone looking for an example.

Answer (score 4):

Let's take a step back here and re-state the problem. We have this clause:

```
y.Average(r => r.Field<decimal>("Rate"))
```

Where `y` is a group of rows.  Let's suppose that the group has been computed correctly; if it has not been computed correctly then fix that problem first.

The problem given is that the lambda can fail because the rate field can contain null, empty, or a non-decimal string.  The goal state is to *discard* such records *before* computing the average.

The correct solution here is to solve the problem in multiple small, clearly correct steps. First, get the data into a good format; we wish "null, empty, malformed" to all be represented as a null decimal:

```
// Consider making this an extension method!
static decimal? ToDecimal(string s)
{
  if (s == null) return null;
  decimal d;
  if (decimal.TryParse(s, out d))
    return d;
  return null;
}
```

Super. Now let's use it. Next step is to use this tool to turn `y` to a sequence of strings:

```
y.Select(r => r.Field<string>("Rate"))
```

OK we have a sequence of strings. Now make that into a sequence of nullable decimals:

```
 .Select(ToDecimal)
```

If that syntax looks weird to you, you can always say

```
.Select(r => ToDecimal(r))
```

if you prefer.

Now we have a sequence of nullable decimals.  Discard the nulls.

```
.Where(r => r.HasValue)
```

Now we have a sequence of non-null nullable decimals. Make a sequence of decimals.

```
.Select(r => r.Value)
```

Now we have a sequence of non-nullable decimals.  Take the average:

```
.Average()
```

And we're done.

I would echo the caution of a commenter on the post that you should be careful applying `Where` to a sequence that is then passed to `Average`. The average of a zero-item sequence is not defined.

Also, I note here that I optimized this answer for *pedagogical clarity*. There are a number of ways to solve this problem and some of them are shorter than what I've shown here. This solution has the benefit of being a series of small steps each of which gets us closer to a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the step-wise explanation that help to understand what is going on. Could this work inside a single LINQ statement or would I have to break out the steps?

Comment: @webworm: I would keep the `ToDecimal` helper method outside the query, but everything else can certainly go into one big query.

Comment: Thanks @EricLippert. That makes sense as it is an extension method. Just need to figure out how to combine the steps in the LINQ statement. Thanks again!

Comment: @EricLippert you don't need ``if (s == null) return null;`` in the method. ``null`` is not parsed value, then will gives ``false``.

Comment: @Sajid: I prefer code to be extremely clear about how it handles nulls. Is it *obvious* from the call site that `TryParse` handles a null correctly? Don't make the reader of the method slow down to consider whether that is the case or not.

Comment: Is the use of `r => r => r.Field<decimal>("Rate")` intentional? I have never seen the lambda operator used in such a manner. Looks like an additional lambda parameter and operator. What am I missing?

Comment: @webworm: Cut-n-paste error, fixed, thanks. However, that is a legal use of lambdas if you vary the formal parameter names. `x => y => x + y` is convertible to `Func<int, Func<int, int>>`. That is, we can say `Func<int, Func<int, int>> makeAdder = x => y => x + y;` and then we can say `Func<int, int> addTen = makeAdder(10); int z = addTen(20); // 30`

Comment: @webworm: Or we could say `makeAdder(10)(20)` and get 30 directly.  This technique is common in functional languages; the process of taking one function of two arguments apart into a function of one argument that returns a function of one argument is called "Currying" after Haskell Curry, the logician who popularized this technique; it enables a technique called "partial evaluation", which is shown by my "makeAdder" function -- it partially evaluates x + y by evaluating its argument and storing that as the value for x.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to convert the Rates to decimals before you start using them, or in fact: convert all types to the type they really represent.

```
var result = exchangeRatesTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select(row => new
    {
        OriginalCurrency = row.Field<string>("OriginalCurrency"),
        TargetCurrency = row.Field<string>("TargetCurrency"),
        Rate = row.Field<decimal?>("Rate")),
    })

    // Do the GroupBy and Average:
    .GroupBy(row => new {OriginalCurrency, TargetCurrency},  // keySelector
    row => row.Rate                                          // elementSelector
    (key, ratesWithThisKey) =>                                // resultSelector
    {
        OriginalCurrency = key.OriginalCurrency,
        TargetCurrency = key.TargetCurrency,

        // AverageRate: use only Rates that have a value
        AverageRate = ratesWithThisKey.Where(rate => rate.HasValue())
                                      .Average();
    });
```

A null value in a DataRow is a DbNull, `Field<decimal?>` will automatically convert this to null. If you also have empty strings that should be converted to null consider:

```
Rate = String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Field<string>("Rate") ?
              (decimal?)null,                       // null if null or empty string
              row.Field<decimal?>("Rate")           // otherwise a decimal?
```

### possible way for improvement

Quite often people decouple the data from the way this data is serialized (stored). This has the advantage, that your code is independent of how and where the data is stored. If later on you decide to store your data in CSV-format, JSon, in SQLite, or in a heavy database management system, your code won't have to change.

Because you make the data independent of how the data is stored, it is easier to create test data for unit tests.

Similarly, if your tables change, there is only one place that you have to change the conversion from table to the data it represents; only one place where you have to test this conversion.

This is quite often done in a Repository class. The Repository is a kind of facade, or adapter between your datatable and the sequence of items that the rows in the datatable represent.

Quite often this conversion is done using an extension method. This will make it look like a LINQ method. See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
class ExchangeRate
{
    public string OriginalCurrency {get; set;}
    public string TargetCurrency {get; set;}
    public decimal? Rate {get; set;}
}

public static IEnumerable<ExchangeRate> ToExchangeRates(this DataTable dataTable)
{
    return dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToExchangeRates();
}

public static IEnumerable<ExchangeRateRate> ToExchangeRates(this IEnumerable<DataRow> source)
{
    // TODO: exception if source is null
    return source.Select(row => new
    {
        OriginalCurrency = row.Field<string>("OriginalCurrency"),
        TargetCurrency = row.Field<string>("TargetCurrency"),
        Rate = row.Field<decimal?>("Rate")),
    }
}
```

(Or use the alternative for Rate).

Usage:

```
DataTable exchangeRatesTable = ...
var exchangeRates = exchangeRatesTable.ToExchangeRates();
```

You can use this for all functions where you plan to use the exchangeRatesTable. Now you don't have to type the part `dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => new ...)` over and over. Also there is only one place where you have to test it.

Now that we master extension methods, let's also create an extension method to calculate the averages:

```
class AverageExchangeRate
{
    public string OriginalCurrency {get; set;}
    public string TargetCurrency {get; set;}
    public decimal AverageExchangeRate {get; set;}
}

public static IEnumerable<AverageExchangeRate> ToAverageExchangeRates(this IEnumerable<ExchangeRate> exchangeRates)
{
    // TODO: exception if exchangeRates is null
    return exchangeRates.GroupBy(row => new {OriginalCurrency, TargetCurrency},  // keySelector
    row => row.Rate                                          // elementSelector
    (key, ratesWithThisKey) =>                                // resultSelector
    {
        OriginalCurrency = key.OriginalCurrency,
        TargetCurrency = key.TargetCurrency,

        // AverageRate: use only Rates that have a value
        AverageRate = ratesWithThisKey.Where(rate => rate.HasValue())
                                      .Average();
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
DataTable exchangeRatesTable = ...
var exchangeRates = exchangeRatesTable.ToExchangeRates()
                                      .ToAverageExchangeRates();
```

The nice thing is that you can intertwine this with other LINQ statements:

```
var DollarRates = exchangeRatesTable
       .ToExchangeRates()
       .Where(exchangeRate => exchangeRate.OriginalCurrency == "USD" 
                           || exchangeRate.TargetCurrency == "USD")
       .ToAverageExchangeRates()
       // if desired: continue with other LINQ statements
       .Where(...)
       .ToList();
```